# why am i getting this error : HardhatError: HH8:?why it goes away if i am not using .env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, solidity, hardhat

I am following a solidity hardhat tutorial. Learning to deploy a contract to sepolia testnet.

Shows error when I am using environmental variables to provide network details.I cud deploy the contract if i provide the details directly.

`hardhat.config.js`

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL;
const SEPOLIA_PVT_KEY = process.env.SEPOLIA_PVT_KEY;
const SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID = process.env.SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID;

// commented section is working
// const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL =
//     "https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/SYu8cyWG0EOfcfZVehXUoPMXW91om6Hd";
// const SEPOLIA_PVT_KEY =
//     "***********************************************************";
// const SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID = 11155111;
module.exports = {
    defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
    networks: {
        sepolia: {
            url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
            accounts: [SEPOLIA_PVT_KEY],
            chainId: SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID,
        },
    },
    solidity: "0.8.18",
};

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async () => {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

    for (const account of accounts) {
        console.log(account.address);
    }
});
```

`.env`

```
SEPOLIA_RPC_URL=https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/SYu8cyWG0EOfcfZVehXUoPMXW91om6Hd
SEPOLIA_PVT_KEY=***************************************************************
SEPOLIA_CHAIN_ID=11155111
```

`error` when using environment variables

```bash
blue@DESKTOP-A6GBG6O:~/solidity/hardhat-sss$ yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/blue/solidity/hardhat-sss/node_modules/.bin/hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network sepolia
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value {"url":"https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/SYu8cyWG0EOfcfZVehXUoPMXW91om6Hd",
"accounts":["************************************************************"],"chainId":"11155111"} 
for HardhatConfig.networks.sepolia - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkConfig.
```

Comment: I cud pinpoint the issue to chain id. Rest are working fine when used as env variables.